# How to set ItestResult.SetAttribute("Key",Value) to be globally accessible

Tags: testng, listener, custom-attributes, playwright-java

I'm developing a wrapper Framework for Playwright Java and I have my custom wrapper class which creates a page , and also I have my custom listener class which takes screenshot on failure , now I want to add the page that gets created to ItestResult Attributes , but Im running into a null pointer

**Below is a sample test class method**

```
 @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUp(ITestContext iTestContext) throws InterruptedException {
        page = getPage("Default");
    }


    @Test(priority = 0, description = "Verify Navigation to Application successfully")
    public void navDishLandPage1() throws InterruptedException {
        page.goTo("https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.playwright/playwright/1.31.0");
        Assert.assertEquals(page.getTitle(), "TTT");
    }
```

**Below is my wrapper Method to create a page**

```
Page scrnShtPg; //used to store the page getting created
    public BaseBrowser retrievePage(Browser browser, ThreadLocalContextMap contextMap, BrowserContext browserContext, String contextKey) {
        if (contextMap.containsKey(contextKey)) {
            browserContext = contextMap.get(contextKey);
        } else {
            contextMap.put(contextKey, browser.newContext(new Browser.NewContextOptions().setIgnoreHTTPSErrors(true)));
            browserContext = contextMap.get(contextKey);
        }
        //testing
        scrnShtPg=browserContext.newPage();
        ITestResult itr = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
        itr.setAttribute("Page_Reference", scrnShtPg); //Feeding the page to ItestResult
        //testing
        return new BaseBrowser(scrnShtPg);
    }
```

**Below is my custom listener class to take screenshot**

```
@Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        JsonObject element = null;
        byte[] bufferImage=null;

     
            Page page = (Page) iTestResult.getAttribute("Page_Reference"); //throws a null pointer exception
            bufferImage = page.screenshot();
       

        try {
            element = SyscoLabReporting.getElement(iTestResult, bufferImage);
            elements.add(element);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

**Expecting solution**

I want to initialize my getPage(); outside of @Test , maybe in @BeforeTest , @BeforeClass and then to be accessible from my custom listener class to take screenshot

> **Note - If I use my getPage(); inside @Test it works without any issue**

Comment: What is your `getPage()` method?

Comment: @AlexeyR. its a wrapper method created to get a page .....

->

public BaseBrowser getPage(String contextKey) {
        if (BROWSER1 == null)
            BROWSER1 = new PlayWrightFactory(PlayWrightConstants.SYSTEM_BROWSER1).browser;
        return retrievePage(BROWSER1, contexts_browser1, context1, contextKey);
    }

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved by using ItestContext in the page creation method as below

```
    scrnShtPg=browserContext.newPage();
    ITestContext iTestContext = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext();
    iTestContext.setAttribute("Page_Reference", scrnShtPg);
```

and you can call the set value in your listener class by

```
iTestResult.getTestContext().getAttribute("Page_Reference");
```